# Root mean square error of two functions

Tags: approximation

How can I calculate the root mean square error of two functions like

\begin{align*}
f(x) &= \sin(x)\\
g(x) &= x-\frac{1}{6}x^3
\end{align*}

in $[0, 2\pi]$ range?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an integral, as we are now dealing with infinitely many points. Thus we have
$$\sqrt{\frac{\int_0^{2\pi}(\sin(x)-(x-\frac{1}{6}x^3))^2dx}{\int_0^{2\pi}dx}}$$
The square root of the mean square of the difference between the two functions.

Comment: heh I don't know how to calculate this

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sqrt((integrate+(sin(x)+-+(x+-+(1%2F6)*x%5E3))%5E2+from+0+to+2pi)+%2F+(integrate+x+from+0+to+2pi)) I use this, but it is "incorrect" i gues

Comment: Yes, that is incorrect, because you are just taking the square root of the integral. Not even an average difference, never-mind the average square of the difference.
The root mean square error is the square root of the average square of the difference. Thus the above method is the correct way of doing it.

Comment: Also, if you are having trouble calculating, I suggest plugging it into WolframAlpha, as you did with your method.